# N-Tier Data Layer implementation with Entity Framework 5 Code-First and POCOs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

It seems as if using N-Tier architecture with EF implies that you're forced to instantiate a new DbContext object for your Data Tier's load methods, and then instantiate another one when trying to save.

The downstream implication of this is that the entity that was loaded in the beginning of the workflow is no longer in state when you go to save, and thus saving the calls to something like ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry() returns false, when in fact the entity being saved did originate in the database. The result is that saving our edits result in adds.

This seems like a fairly common workflow in a fairly common architecture. Is there something obvious I've missed?

Comment: They recommend WebAPI or WCF Data Services for N-Tier Data Access. I didn't like any of that so I managed to make `DbContext` work with `Self Tracking Entities`. Now I send my entities via regular WCF and they come back with Self-Tracking changes and I `ApplyChanges()` in my `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext` and call `SaveChanges()`. Everyone's happy so far.

Comment: In our company current project we have the same setup as you. EF5/POCO/3-Tiers; The "Downside" is that you have to pass along your data through your tiers. But in the long run, your code will be cleaner and more maintainable. Oh, and you lose Lazy Loading!

Comment: @Tico When you say "pass along your data" do you mean the wiring the DbContext object into your workflows, so that you save on the same instance that loaded your entities?

Comment: @TIco Lazy loading can still be enabled for `server-only` operations such as report queries and heavy business-logic related data access.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Let me try to explain. The project structure is similar to this pic (found at google):(http://i.imgur.com/IIhBeX9.jpg)  One Layer has the POCOs (VO Layer), the other one is the BLL (Business Logic Layer), the DAL(Data Access Layer) and UI (whatever you like). The UI and DAL are 'dumb', so to speak. The responsibility for the logic is within the BLL. So, you have to query the DB, pass to BLL and to UI (same way around)

Comment: @HighCore Sure, you're right, but to our purposes it became "worthless" for some internal rules.

Comment: @Tico what do you think about my approach in the first comment?

Comment: @Tico Rather than trying to understand IoC on our data later to facilitate keeping our DbContext in scope, or wiring our DbContext through all our workflows, we've taken advantage of the fact that all of our entities implement surrogate keys so that we can implement the AddOrUpdate pattern described on the EF site where we attached as Modified if Id != 0. Thoughts?

Comment: @HighCore I can only @-tag one user per comment, but the above is for you too.

Comment: @bwerks We did start like you're describing right now. The 'problems' are starting to show up now. When we first started, we didn't know about MVVM, IoC, and all. I do believe that you can start right away, this approach (Modified id Id != 0) looks ok to me. But, read about which frameworks you're about to use! Other than that I agree with your first comment.

Comment: Err, for the record, that earlier comment was supposed to read "trying to UNDERTAKE IoC," hah. My mistake. We considered implementing Visitor as a means of centralizing our workflow logic & data (including the DbContext) but we decided against it when comparing the cost of implementation against "Id != 0."

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in trying [N-Tier Entity Framework](http://ntieref.codeplex.com/) which is open source available on CodePlex and perfectly addresses your needs.